# Nth-child in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I have an HTML Code like below:

```
<div>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="a"></div>
<div>
```

I want to add class "b" to the last child of the block using angularJS. Please note that I don't have the code as an static block and it made using a DataList and

```
<div class="a"></div>
```

is as a template so I only can change when created.
In jQuery I can easily use nth-child and addclass. I saw some sample in angularjs that use $index but here I don't have an ng-repeat so I cannot use it.

Comment: you need to implement in angular js or jquery ?

Comment: angularJS. as I mention it is easy doing in jquery

Comment: It's not clear why you aren't using AngularJS to generate this HTML, e.g. with ng-repeat, etc. Can you explain that?

Comment: Because it is created by a CMS on server side.It is a kind of datalist in asp.net that made it for me. I am not looking for a more complicated way. I am looking for a way as easy as jquery nth-child.

Comment: The trouble is that doing direct DOM manipulations is not what AngularJS is about. If you want to modify the DOM, you can go ahead and try using jQuery to do that, but [do so at your own risk](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#dom-manipulation). If you want to use AngularJS, you should focus on doing things the Angular way, which means using directives in your HTML view and controllers.